# Convert jQuery toggle animations to Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I have the following jQuery based animations for toggling the sidebar :

```
$('.sa-fixedNav_toggle').click(function () {
        $('.sa-fixedNav_positon').toggleClass('sa-fixedNav_size-grow')
        $('.pa-content_layout').toggleClass('pa-content_push-right')
        $('.sa-fixedNav_expand-button').toggleClass('sa-fixedNav_expand-nav')
        
        if($('.sa-fixedNav_positon').width() == 78) {
            sideNavContentShow()
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(() => {
                sideNavContentHide()
            },150);
        }
    })
  function sideNavContentShow () {
      $('.sa-fixedNav_content-expand').removeClass('hidden');
      $('.sa-fixedNav_option-expand-icon').removeClass('hidden');
       $('.sa-fixedNav_option-expandDown-icon').removeClass('hidden')
  }
    function sideNavContentHide () {
        $('.sa-fixedNav_content-expand').addClass('hidden');
        $('.sa-fixedNav_option-expand-icon').addClass('hidden');
        $('.sa-fixedNav_option-expandDown-icon').addClass('hidden')
  }
    
    $('.sa-fixedNav_nav-links').click(function () {
        $('.sa-fixedNav_option-expandDown-icon').toggleClass('sa-fixedNav_expand-hidden')
        $('.sa-fixedNav_option-expand-icon').toggleClass('sa-fixedNav_expand-hidden')
    })
```

Now I am trying to convert this to Angular. I have tried using `Renderer2` and `@ViewChild`. But in there there is no option for `toggleClass` and no method to get the width. How can this be done in Angular ?

Comment: With the `viewchild` you can get element reference. Using that element reference and using vanila javascript -> eleRef.classList.add() / .remove()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like below, using `@ViewChild()` and `ElementRef` and `classList`

```
<div #someelementone class="some-element-class toggle-class-one">
  Test
</div>
<div #someelementtwo class="some-element-class toggle-class-two">
  Tes2
</div>
<div #someelementthree class="some-element-class toggle-class-three">
  Tes3
</div>

<button (click)="updateElementClasses()">Toggle Classes</button>
```

In the ts file

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('someelementone') someElementOne: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('someelementtwo') someElementTwo: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('someelementthree') someElementThree: ElementRef;

  updateElementClasses() {
    this.toggleClass(this.someElementOne, 'toggle-class-one');
    this.toggleClass(this.someElementTwo, 'toggle-class-two');
    this.toggleClass(this.someElementThree, 'toggle-class-three');
  }

  toggleClass(eleRef: ElementRef, classStr: string) {
    eleRef.nativeElement.classList.toggle(classStr);
  }
}
```

You can find the working Stackblitz from [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dmah7c)

> For the `classList` API, there exists two methods `add()` and `remove()`.
> Where you can add and remove classes for specific elements

Comment: You are awesome.